# Conflicting versions of openssl with indy library

Tags: c++, openssl, c++builder, indy

Using Embarcadero C++Builder with bcc32c clang compiler.

Up until recently, our project used the OpenSSL library tagged version `1.0.2` in our code. 90% of our code uses this library directly, but we also have some code that goes through the [Indy library](https://www.indyproject.org/) too, and that obviously is using the same version of OpenSSL, hence no issues.

We upgraded our OpenSSL lib to use tagged version `3.0.0` and that code is working with very little changes required. However, the Indy version is broken now, as it needs to use the older tagged version.

Is their a way this can work in the same project? Using two different versions of the library.

The new dlls/libs are named differently;

`libeay32 -> libcrypto_static`

`ssleay32 -> libssl_static`

Comment: Indy's default SSLIOHandler does not support OpenSSL 1.1+/3.0. However, there is a [pending PR](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299) in Indy's GitHub repo for a new SSLIOHandler that does. Try installing the latest Indy and PR into your project, and update your code to use the new SSLIOHandler, and see if that helps you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So this is the recommended action to using the Indy library with the new clang compiler then right? As the version 1.0.2 only comes with libs built with Borland compiler. Otherwise we will have a mismatch of compilers or am I missing something here?

Comment: What I described has nothing to do with clang. You are mixing different OpenSSL libraries in the same process, that won't work. If you need to use a modern OpenSSL version in the rest of your code, you will have to update Indy to use the same OpenSSL version (you might also need something like [this PR](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/321), which is not incorporated into the main code yet, or even into [the SSLIOHandler PR](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299)). If you need clang lib files, you can generate them from the OpenSSL DLLs themself. But Indy doesn't use lib files.

Comment: @RemyLebeau how can I generate clang lib files from the dlls. Are you referring to implib? And this will remove the compiler mismatch warning?

Comment: "*Are you referring to implib?*" - yes. "*And this will remove the compiler mismatch warning?*" - what warning? You didn't say anything earlier about a warning.